# Web Scraping: Xpath Code Returns "Script out of bounds message" in R

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table in a for loop, however the code returns the following error, "Error in Raw_Dividends[[1]] : subscript out of bounds".  I have a suspicion that the Xpath might not be correct, however I've tried many similar xpath codes from the HTML code and none have worked.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Code as below:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)

url   = "https://www.dividenddata.co.uk/ftse-dividend-history.py?market=ftse100"
xpath = '/html/body/section/div[3]/div[1]/div/table'

url_html                      <- read_html(url)
Stock_Table                   <- url_html %>% html_nodes(xpath = xpath) %>%  html_table(fill = T)
Stock_Table                   <- Stock_Table[[1]]
Stock_Table                   <- Stock_Table[,c(1,2)]


Dividends <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(Stock_Table)) {

url                  = paste0("https://www.dividenddata.co.uk/dividendhistory.py?epic=",Stock_Table[1,1])
xpath                = '/html/body/section/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div'
Raw_Dividends        <- url_html %>% html_nodes(xpath = xpath) %>% 
html_table(fill = T)
Raw_Dividends        <- Raw_Dividends[[1]]
Raw_Dividends$Symbol <- rep(Stock_Table[1,i],nrow(Stock_Table))
Dividends            <- rbind(Dividends, Raw_Dividends)

}
```

Comment: You have a couple of issues in the line `url = paste0(..." ,Stock_Table[1,1])` the loop is referencing the first stock only, you need to replace with `=",Stock_Table[i,1])`  Also inside the loop, you are missing the call to `read_html` to the newly created url

Comment: Thanks Dave2e - that's solved it.